# Store the oauth access_token or ask a new one each 'session'

Tags: security, oauth, token

I'm playing around with the api of a service that supports oauth. I managed to retrieve the access_token from the service and I'm now able to call the various endpoints of the api. So far so good.

Now my question is: How long do I hold on to this access_token I received. Is this a token I keep forever, or does this expire after some time? I'm working on a desktop app, so I a have two options:

- I request a new token every time the application is opened
- I store the token somewhere and re-use it

What are the best practices around the storage of this token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the Access Token is stored across sessions. There is an expiration (with OAuth 2.0), but the Refresh Token is then used to retrieve a new Access Token. If you don't store the tokens, then you would need to have the end user re-authorize everytime they want to use your application (which is probably not the experience you are looking for).

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance, but this is exactly the guidance I was looking for